# eCommerce search box accessibility/navigation

Tags: html, accessibility

I'm looking to build something like the following and I can't find best practices in terms of accessibility & navigation.

I've been reading lot of articles and found that `aria-autocomplete` to be useful with `role="searchbox"`, `aria-owns`, `aria-controls`, etc. But honestly I'm not sure.

On the navigation side, it isn't straightforward to decide the "correct" flow I should use. For example, if the input is focused and ArrowDown is pressed, it would make sense to focus on the first product item ("Up to 24H Redness Eraser"). Once there, using the arrows could navigate the product results. But then, how can the user move to "Trending Categories" and viceversa?

(1) My first approach was to do that and when the focus is on the first product result and ArrowLeft is pressed, move the focus to the first item on left panel ("Lipstick") and let move through the suggestions using ArrowDown/ArrowUp, updating results on the right when the suggestion is "selected". Then, when ArrowRight is pressed, the focus moves to the first product result.

Also, whenever the focus is on first product item or first left side panel suggestion and ArrowUp is pressed, the input text is focused.

(2) But then I was asked to let the component to be configured with the suggestions panel in the right side and all that navigation flow got weird, because now it doesn't make any sense to move from results to suggestions from the first product item using arrows (first item is at the top left and the suggestions are at the right of the third item).

My questions:

- What would be the correct way to make this component accesible?
- Would you say (1) is "correct"?
- How can I solve (2)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're over-engineering it. Keep it simple and let the browser handle keyboard focus as much as possible.

Many users are not familiar with using the arrow keys to navigate. Most will try to use <kbd>TAB</kbd>. If your products are links (<a>), then they'll naturally be keyboard focusable with the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key.

Is your search field just a simple text input or does it display search suggestions in a dropdown list? If the latter, then you should follow the [combobox pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/combobox/), which makes use of `aria-autocomplete`, `aria-controls` and other attributes you mentioned. If it's a simple text field, then you don't need those attributes.

Does the product list update as you type in the search field? I didn't see anything in the screenshot that says how many results there are. If things update as you type, that's another accessibility consideration ([WCAG 4.1.3 Status Messages](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#status-messages)) and will require [`aria-live`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-live).

From the layout in the screenshot, I'd expect to <kbd>TAB</kbd> from the search field to

1. "Trending Categories" (assuming "lipstick" is a keyboard focusable element such as a link)
2. "Suggestions" (again, assuming "reds..." is a link)
3. Product list

Since you visually have the suggestions on the left, most users would expect to tab to that area before the products (because people expect to tab from left to right).